# x1 - undefined (вроде бы не должен быть)

Tags: javascript

Есть код , вычисляющий точку пересечения отрезков(скопировал его).

Вылетает ошибка что `x1 - undefined`.

```js
function d(х1, у1, х2, у2, х3, у3, х4, у4) {
  let x, y;
  x = ((x1 * y2 - x2 * y1) * (x4 - x3) - (x3 * y4 - x4 * y3) * (x2 - x1)) / ((y1 - y2) * (x4 - x3) - (y3 - y4) * (x2 - x1));
  y = ((y3 - y4) * x - (x3 * y4 - x4 * y3)) / (x4 - x3);
  return x, y;
}
console.log(d(0, 0, 120, 90, 0, 60, 120, 60));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вперемешку русские и английские символы нарочно используете?

```js
function d(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4) {
  let x, y;
  x = ((x1 * y2 - x2 * y1) * (x4 - x3) - (x3 * y4 - x4 * y3) * (x2 - x1)) / ((y1 - y2) * (x4 - x3) - (y3 - y4) * (x2 - x1));
  y = ((y3 - y4) * x - (x3 * y4 - x4 * y3)) / (x4 - x3);
  return x, y;
}
console.log(d(0, 0, 120, 90, 0, 60, 120, 60));
```

Comment: даже с толку немного сбило сразу

Answer (score 1):

Твоя ошибка из-за того, что перепутал кириллицу и латиницу... перемешанные аргументы и переменные разные..

```js
function d(x1, y1) {
  let x, y;
  x = x1 * y1
  y = x1 + y1
  return x, y;
}
console.log(d(120, 60));
```